# Plotly.js Parallel Coordinates: How to Hide Tick Text but keep label?

Tags: plotly, parallel-coordinates

I'm making Parallel coordinates using Plotly.js. I'm asked to hide the tick text on all the yaxis, but keep all the labels. Could anyone please help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: I tried
var layout = {
 showticklabels: false
}; It didn't work

Comment: I think it should be var layout = { yaxis: { showticklabels: false } }; but doesn't seem to work either